# Using Excel PowerQuery, is there a way to load a query to the original table?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to use PowerQuery to read in a table of raw transactions (in a csv file) and combine it with a table of running transactions. The hitch is that the running transactions table contains manually-create labels.

For example, `runningTable` could be

| Date | Amount | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 5.52 | Some notes |
| 2020-01-02 | -4.25 | Other notes |

The `Notes` column is manually entered by the user to label the context for that transaction.

`rawTable` could be
| Date | Amount |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2020-01-01 | 5.52 |
| 2020-01-02 | -4.25 |
| 2020-01-03 | 10.00 |
| 2020-01-04 | 12.00 |

Since there are more dates in `rawTable`, I need to update `runningTable` to include the latest data. Currently, using PowerQuery, I can pretty easily read in both tables, do some transformations and filters, append one to the other, and output a new `runningTable2` with all the notes from `runningTable`, like so:

| Date | Amount | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 5.52 | Some notes |
| 2020-01-02 | -4.25 | Other notes |
| 2020-01-03 | 10.00 |  |
| 2020-01-04 | 12.00 |  |

The problem is that I want `runningTable` itself to be updated since edits in `runningTable2` just get over-written when I run the query again. The best I can manage at the moment is to manually copy and paste `runningTable2` onto `runningTable`, thereby replacing that input table.

But is there a way to do this automatically in Excel?

Comment: I [posted here](https://ricardodiaz.co/tablas-autoreferenciadas-en-power-query-que-respetan-valores-en-columnas-agregadas-al-actualizarse/) how to do this, but it's in spanish. If you only read english google `Power Query self reference tables`

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks! You gave me just what I needed to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Ricard Diaz's comment provided the term that was missing from my vocabulary (i.e., "self reference tables"). It was exactly what I needed to find a solution.

https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Basically, you read in the table without the `Other notes` column and do your transformations etc., then you read in the output table again merging in the `Other notes` column. The "key" here is that you need a key or index column to properly merge in the results. I already had one though I didn't mention it in the question.